# sudo apt update: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'

Tags: apt, updates

I am randomly seeing the following error on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.

```
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for david: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]           
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                    
0% [1 InRelease gpgv 242 kB] [4 InRelease 2,281 B/74.6 kB 3%]terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  random_device::__x86_rdrand(void)
Aborted
```

Sometimes a reboot solves the issue, sometimes not. Currently not. At one point it seemed to be related to urbackup, but stopping the service doesn't fix the problem today.

Comment: That's interesting. I have disabled the "Execute Disable Bit" in the server BIOS and it works. Don't know if this is a permanent or temporary solution.

Comment: You should post that an an answer instead of a comment before your question gets closed...

Comment: @Fabby answered :-)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround mentioned in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045582/sudo-apt-update-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdruntime-er/1068028#comment1705194_1045582) aside, it appears that you've been affected by [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1784796) It appears that there was a problem with insufficient entropy. This is now reported to have been fixed in [apt 1.7.0~alpha2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/1.7.0~alpha2) It doesn't appear to be available for supported versions in the repositories at this moment although it may be soon. The source is available at the previous link. However apt_1.7.0~alpha3_amd64.deb is available from [the cosmic branch](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/apt) if you want to attempt to avoid compiling from [source.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/1.7.0~alpha2) Personally I would compile as using the cosmic deb in a previous version may break things, In which case you have the pieces.

Comment: Upgoated...  **;-)**